# Oracle fully patched install

Tags: oracle10g

How do I create a fully patched version of Oracle 10g for install?

Comment: Do you mean something like slipstreaming?

Comment: yes, like slipstreaming.

Comment: Oracle exists, in part, to provide high paying jobs to specialists who can deal with the complexities of installation and patching their complex software. Please stop trying to rock the boat. :)

Comment: Yeah, if it worked like SQL Server or MySql we'd all be out of a job...

Comment: There are two things: patched binaries, patching oracle specific sql stuff that exists in the oracle table spaces, esp those in sys/system schema. I used to tar up fully patched oracle DB home, had a little script to change some host names. It is doable. I left oracle field 3 years; I forgot all tiny details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install, Patch, and clone.

Oh. And read the documentation too:

- "[Oracle Software Cloning using Oracle Universal Installer](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b16227/oui7_cloning.htm)"
- "[Cloning an Oracle Home on Linux-x86](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b15660/app_cloning.htm)" (exist for others O/S & hardware)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can, sorry.

The best you can do for now is look at Oracle [Patch Set Updates](http://blogs.oracle.com/gridautomation/2009/08/revisiting_patch_management_-.html) which are quarterly collections of critical and important patches, which can be mostly automated.

Answer (score 0):

What platform?  On Unix, I regularly do the install, apply the desired patches, and then tar it up for install elsewhere.   I'm not sure this works so well on Windows because of the registry entries.